# Admob banner not showing and crashing application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have developed an application in android studio and I am trying to add a banner at the bottom of the screen. I have tried putting the banner in a separate activity but then it doesn't show up on screen. I then figured I have to put in the the activity displayed on the screen so I tried putting the code related to the banner in the Main Activity put then the application crashes instantly when I run in.

I do not know what the problem is as I have followed the developer Google guide and several youtube tutorials. Any help or suggestions appreciated.

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string> //in strings.xml

<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- permission> // AndroidManifest.xml. Also have user permissions here.
```

---

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG = "Application";
        AdView mAdView;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest); // in activity along with a number of imports necessary and the rest of the application. Also tried this in admob banner activity
```

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView> //in activity_main.xml. Also tried this in admob banner xml.
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
2019-02-04 17:35:12.430 6334-6334/com.uberspot.a2048 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.uberspot.a2048, PID: 6334
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uberspot.aApplication/com.uberspot.aApplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:403)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.uberspot.a2048.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you please post stack trace of the crash in logcat?

Comment: Hi I added it in my post!

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states that you should use `Theme.Appcompat` or descendant.

So make sure your `AppTheme` parent is `AppCompat` in `styles.xml`.
For example:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```